# Using the 'only' route filter in route groups

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a basic, say, blog structure made in Laravel. Because of keeping things DRY, the public and the administration share the controllers for posts, polls, etc. I did that by routing using the `only` filter (I guess it's a filter?)

```
/*  
    The public can access only index and show ::resource routes
        - domain.tld/posts
        - domain.tld/posts/{id}
        - domain.tld/polls
        - domain.tld/polls/{id}
        - domain.tld/categories
        - domain.tld/categories/{id}
        - domain.tld/tags
        - domain.tld/tags/{id}

*/
Route::resource('posts', 'PortalPostsController', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);
Route::resource('polls', 'PortalPollsController', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);
Route::resource('categories', 'PortalCategoriesController', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);
Route::resource('tags', 'PortalTagsController', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);

/*
    Administration uses the same PortalSomethingController but can access
    all routes by prefixing administration/ to the URL:

        - domain.tld/administration/posts
        - domain.tld/administration/posts/create
        ... all of other administration/resource('posts') routes

        ... all administration/resource('polls') routes
        ... all administration/resource('categories') routes
        ... all administration/resource('tags') routes
*/
Route::group(['prefix' => 'administration'], function() {
    Route::resource('posts', 'PortalPostsController');
    Route::resource('polls', 'PortalPollsController');
    Route::resource('categories', 'PortalCategoriesController');
    Route::resource('tags', 'PortalTagsController');
});
```

Now, to keep things dry, I want to avoid defining ['only' => ['index', 'show']] on every single Route::resource for limiting the public access. So, something like this:

```
// for public access
Route::group(['only' => ['index', 'show']], function() {
    Route::resource('posts', 'PortalPostsController');
    Route::resource('polls', 'PortallPollsController');
    Route::resource('categories', 'PortallCategoriesController');
    Route::resource('tags', 'PortallTagsController');
}); 

// for admin access
Route::group(['prefix' => 'administration'], function() {
    Route::resource('posts', 'PortalPostController');
    Route::resource('polls', 'PortallPollsController');
    Route::resource('categories', 'PortallCategoriesController');
    Route::resource('tags', 'PortallTagsController');
});
```

How would I go about doing that, if possible? Also, as you can see, both the public and admin route groups use the same resources (with the public being limited to only some routes) and the same controllers, so is it possible to DRY it up even more? For example:

```
// define shared resources
Route::group(['name' => 'sharedResources'], function() {
    Route::resource('posts', 'PortalPostController');
    Route::resource('polls', 'PortallPollsController');
    Route::resource('categories', 'PortallCategoriesController');
    Route::resource('tags', 'PortallTagsController');
});

// public access
Route::group(['only' => ['index', 'show']], function() {
    // use sharedResources
});

// admin access
Route::group(['prefix' => 'administration'], function() {
    // use sharedResources
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wildcard as the first URI component of your route, and then that wildcard will be available to your controller. The only problem here is that if the wildcard is the first segment of your URI, you can't make it optional; so you would need to include some prefix for non-administrator routes as well:

```
domain.tld/user/posts
domain.tld/admin/posts
```

If you do that, then you can set up routing something like this:

```
Route::pattern('admin', 'admin|user');
Route::resource('{admin?}/posts', 'PortalPostController');
Route::resource('{admin?}/polls', 'PortalPollsController');
...
```

In your controller, you can then read the $admin prefix, and apply the 'index'/'show' limitation as a beforeFilter in the `__construct` method, if the prefix is 'user'. (To keep things DRY, you can put this filter logic in a BaseController, and have your PortalControllers extend BaseController and call `parent::__construct`.

---

Another option, and a better one if you have control over the configuration of your server, would be to use Domain Routing. Then, regular users would access your site using `domain.tld/posts` or `www.domain.tld/posts`, while administrators would use `admin.domain.tld/posts`. You can capture the first part of the host name, and then handle the `only` filter as a beforeFilter in your Contoller (like above). For a good disussion of this, see the section of Dayle Rees' *Code Bright* on Domain Routing: http://daylerees.com/codebright/advanced-routing.